# Python Convert a list of binary to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, binary

I have a list of 1 and 0 --> `output = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`

I would like to convert that list of ones and zeroes to a string, where each 8 bits in "litlle-endian" represent one letter in "latin1"

So far I have this code (below) which works fine, but I think its quite slow and seem to slow down my script...

```
for i in range(0,len(output),8):
        x=output[i:i+8]
        l="".join([str(j) for j in x[::-1]])
        out_str += chr(int(("0b"+l),base=2))
```

Do you have any faster ideas?

Comment: What are you using this routine for? Are you repeatedly doing this on lists of multiple thousands of different values? I had to run your sample 100,000 times (!) to get more than sub-second timings. If the output is text, I'd have decoded 200,000 characters – about a thousand *pages* in a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a faster solution using a dictionary of tuples for the 256 possible characters:

```
bits = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

chars = { tuple(map(int,f"{n:08b}"[::-1])):chr(n) for n in range(0,256) }

def toChars(bits):
    return "".join(chars[tuple(bits[i:i+8])] for i in range(0,len(bits),8) )
```

*roughly 3x faster than original solution*

[EDIT] and an even faster one using bytes and zip:

```
chars = { tuple(map(int,f"{n:08b}")):n for n in range(256) }
def toChars(bits):
    return bytes(chars[b] for b in zip(*(bits[7-i::8] for i in range(8)))).decode()
```

*about 2x faster than the previous one (on long lists)*

[EDIT2] a bit of explanations for this last one ...

- `b` in the list comprehension will be a tuple of 8 bits
- `chars[b]` will return an integer corresponding to the 8 bits
- `bytes(...).decode()` converts the list of integers to a string based on the chr(n) of each value
- `zip(*(... 8 bit iterators...))` unpacks the 8 striding ranges of bits running in parallel, each from a different starting point

The strategy with the unpacked zip is to go through the bits in steps of 8.   For example, if we were going through 8 parallel ranges, we would get this:

```
 bits[7::8] -> [ 0, 0, ... ]  zip returns: (0,1,0,0,0,1,1)
 bits[6::8] -> [ 1, 1, ... ]               (0,1,1,0,1,1,1)
 bits[5::8] -> [ 0, 1, ... ]               ...
 bits[4::8] -> [ 0, 0, ... ]
 bits[3::8] -> [ 0, 1, ... ]
 bits[2::8] -> [ 0, 1, ... ]
 bits[1::8] -> [ 1, 1, ... ]
 bits[0::8] -> [ 1, 1, ... ]
```

The zip function will take one column of this per iteration and return it as a tuple of bits.

Comment: Great solution! Took me some while to get a grasp of it. I edited my answer with a noob version of your code :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

bits = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
result = []

c = 0
for i,v in enumerate(bits):
    i = i % 8
    c = c | v << i
    if i == 7:
        result.append(chr(c))
        c = 0

print(''.join(result))
```

Testing:

```
$ python ./test.py
Co
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sum` and `enumerate` should be faster, as they are built-ins. Let's time yours and mine, on the same machine.

Run 100,000 times in a loop and tested with `time python3 tmp.py`. (`user` values. For both the amount of `sys` time hovered around 0m0.012s, so it only had a percentual influence on the results.)

Yours: 0m1.624s
Mine is 50% faster: 0m1.063s, with this

```py
output = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

for item in [output[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(output), 8)]:
    out_str += chr(sum(x<<i for i,x in enumerate(item)))
```

Comment: ... since it's only 8 values, [x<<i] can be 'cached' as [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128] and then cross-multiplied or sth. But it's late over here.

Answer (score 1):

I did some measuments of the execution time for all valid solutions. See the results below in the code. Codes are sorted from slowest to fastest. Fatest being the one from [Alain T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5237560/alain-t). I've tested the codes on a quite large list resulting in a string of 200000 characters.

Even for such a large list the execution time is still pretty fast also for my original solution. There has to be an issue somewhere else in my program... :-)

Thank you all for your codes!

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
bits = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0] * 100000
    ### tested code ###
print("Execution time: ", time.time() - start_time, "seconds")


### former solution --> 0.59 seconds
out_str = ""
for i in range(0,len(bits),8):
    x=bits[i:i+8]
    l="".join([str(j) for j in x[::-1]])
    out_str += chr(int(("0b"+l),base=2))


### enumerate and result.append --> 0.48 seconds
result = []
c = 0
for i,v in enumerate(bits):
    i = i % 8
    c = c | v << i
    if i == 7:
        result.append(chr(c))
        c = 0
out_str = ''.join(result)


### sum and enumerate --> 0.45 seconds
out_str = ""
for item in [bits[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(bits), 8)]:
    out_str += chr(sum(x<<i for i,x in enumerate(item)))


### map and chars dictionary --> 0.10 seconds
chars = { tuple(map(int,f"{n:08b}"[::-1])):chr(n) for n in range(0,256) }
def toChars(bits):
    return "".join(chars[tuple(bits[i:i+8])] for i in range(0,len(bits),8) )


### bytes and zip --> 0.06 seconds
chars = { tuple(map(int,f"{n:08b}")):n for n in range(256) }
def toChars(bits):
    return bytes(chars[b] for b in zip(*(bits[7-i::8] for i in range(8)))).decode()
```

EDIT:

I wrote the best (fastest) solution in a more understandable form (not using list comprehensions) so I could step through the code because it took me some while to understand how it works (solution by [Alain T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5237560/alain-t)):

```
bits = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0] * 10
chars = {tuple(map(int,f"{n:08b}")):n for n in range(256)}
temp = []
out = []
for i in range(8):
    temp.append(bits[7-i::8])
unzipped = zip(*temp)
for b in unzipped:
    out.append(bytes([chars[b]]).decode())
print("".join(out))
```

Answer (score -1):

Check whether this is faster:

```
tmp_list = []
for i in range(0,len(output),8):
    byte_value = 0
    for digit in output[i:i+8:-1]:
        byte_value = (byte_value<<1) + digit
    tmp_list.append(chr(byte_value))
out_str = ''.join(tmp_list)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second for cycle be: `for digit in output[i+8:i:-1]`?
But anyway it doesn't seem to work. The result should be `"Co"` for this one.